# How to list, custom page templates usage?

Tags: wordpress

I created a custom page template. And i assign a page its name called like '**Authors**', (but it can be change for my customer).

```
/**
 * Template Name: Authors
 * Authors page template.
 * @package News V2.
 * @version v12096.01-stable
 */
```

The point, 
Could we list which page use my custom page template ? If we how ? Thanks.

Comment: Click `quick edit` on the page you want to assign it to and from the page template select your `Authors` template.

Comment: no i mean, how can list custom template usages via php. Actually i found the sulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getAresAuthorsPage(){
    global $post;
    $args =array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'nopaging' => true,
        'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
        'meta_value' => 'template-authors.php'
    );
    $Crumbpage = get_posts( $args );
    return '<a href="'.get_permalink($Crumbpage[0]).'">ALL AUTHORS</a>';
}
```

we need to use, meta_query for listing that page template usage ;) 
Have a nice one.

Note. Sorry about my really bad English.